# Change navigation list item if user is logged in

Tags: php, jquery, nav, listitem

I have a navigation that is made up of several list items that are dynamically created. One of the "tabs" or items is labelled "Sign Up", however, once the user is logged in (which would indicate they are already "signed up") I want to change the label on the nav item to read "upgrade".

Is it possible to use jQuery to change the text of a selected list item (in this case it's the 4th item) - if that is possible, I can then wrap that in a php if Statement to execute it when user is logged in.

My question is, how do I change the text of a list item using jQuery?

Comment: Why write PHP to write a jQuery function and not just use PHP to `if($loggedin) { echo "Upgrade"; } else { echo "Sign up"; }`

Comment: That's right @AmazingDreams

Comment: Apologies, should've added that the list is dynamically created, so I can't just edit the code for individual list items.

Comment: From the answers below I can now change the list item name. But how about if if I want to add a link to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery you change the text of a list item using

```
$('#element_id').text("new text");
```

however, since you are using php, you can already find out in php if the user has signed in, and from php you can make the list item "sign up" not being displayed at all. There is no need for using jQuery in this situation.

Comment: worked perfectly thanks. I need to use jquery to select the element as the navigation list is dynamically created.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#yourListItemId').text('Your new text!');
```

Specify the selector to access your element.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't agree more with AmazingDreams, using jQuery in your context seems to be redundant. IMHO the logic that you want to execute should be implemented server-side unless if you have a good reason that prohibits you to do so. Here's a naive example in PHP that does what you want:

```
 <?php 
     session_start(); 
     if($_SESSION['loggedIn'] === true): 
 ?>
 <ul>
     <li><a href="#"><?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?></a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Upgrade</a></li>
     <!-- other options -->
 </ul>
 <?php else: ?>
     <?php //header to login.php ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```